# CFBundleSupportedPlatforms issue

Tags: xcode, sdk, osx-yosemite, info.plist, osx-elcapitan

On existing project that always built without issue on 10.10/Xcode 6 I am now getting this error with 10.11/Xcode 7:

Couldn't find platform family in Info.plist CFBundleSupportedPlatforms or Mach-O LC_VERSION_MIN for myBinary

I have 3 pre-complied binaries inside of my project.  They do have their own entitlements files and they are codesigned but they do not have their own Info.plist. I tried adding CFBundleSupportedPlatforms to the main Info.plist with the value MacOSX but it's not resolving the issue.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm running into the same issue

Comment: did anyone ever find a solution here I'm still having the same issue...

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. I have some pre-compiled *nix type binaries (things you would normally call in the command line, which my app calls with NSTask) in my app resources folder. Developer ID workflow works fine. But app validation for MAS distribution fails with exactly the same error you saw. They aren't frameworks so you can't just create a substitute Info.plist inside them. Anyone solved this yet?

Answer (score 2):

I got it working. I happen to be using `Carthage` to manage some framework dependencies, which gives you the `dSYM` files. The solution for me was to ensure I was not including any of the `dSYM` files that Carthage will generate for you into the app's resource bundle.

Comment: That worked for me too.  I found 2 .dSYM files in my Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources, once removed the upload was successful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my application which used SDL framework.
I've fixed it by adding `CFBundleSupportedPlatforms` key as a dict with a single `MacOSX` value into any Info.plist file in any framework I copied into my binary.